# iOS: Value of NSCalendarUnitWeekday is 1 for a Monday

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to parse out the day of the week given a NSDate.

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
comps=[calendar components: NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfMonth | NSCalendarUnitWeekOfYear | NSCalendarUnitWeekday fromDate:date];
```

When the value of date is `2015-11-30 00:58:52 +0000` (this is Monday), the value of `comps.weekday` is printed out as 1

When the value of date as `2015-11-15 09:59:46 +0000` (this is Sunday), the value of `comps.weekday` is also 1.

Comment: Please, show all your code when you creating (receiving) those dates. May be they are wrong.

Answer (score 5):

`NSDateComponents` uses the timezone of the `NSCalendar` to interpret the current day. `NSCalendar` defaults to the using the timezone of the device.

`2015-11-30 00:58:52 UTC` is only a Monday if you are in the `UTC` timezone, or one of the later ones. If you are in the `EST` (-5) timezone, then this would be a Sunday.

If you want to interpret the day of week at the `UTC` timezone then change the `timeZone` property to `[NSTimezone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]`.

Documentation ref: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSDateComponents/timeZone

Comment: Right. The value of comps.weekday should be printed out as 2

Comment: Fixed the typo, 30 Nov is a Monday, 15 Nov is Sunday

Comment: It's `NSCalendar` that is using the current locale and thus the timezone, but other than that, the explanation in this answer seems to be correct.